# How to create through association in Golang GORM?

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

For example, I have the following models

```
type Company struct {
    ID uint `gorm:"PRIMARY_KEY"`
    Name string
    Departments []*Department `gorm:"FOREIGNKEY:CompanyID"`
    Managers []*Manager
}

type Department struct {
    ID uint `gorm:"PRIMARY_KEY"`
    Name string
    Managers []*Manager `gorm:"FOREIGNKEY:DepartmentID"`
    CompanyID uint
}

type Manager struct {
    ID uint `gorm:"PRIMARY_KEY"`
    Name string
    DepartmentID uint
}
```

That is, company has many departments, and department has many managers. How can I create an association between company and manager such that I can say company has many managers through departments?

Is this feature even possible in Go GORM? I am used to seeing this in Rails ActiveRecord

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :departments
    has_many :managers, through: :departments
end
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think gorm has anything like this, but you can probably fake it with [many to many](http://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html).